# What is an effective way to attach this plastic filter to aluminum without drilling?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, aluminum

I have an aluminum angle that is housing an LED strip. I need to attach a UV filter to stop LEDs fading whatever it lights. I ordered a plexi angle that will work as a filter, I just need to figure out how to attach it. I don't want to drill into the aluminum because its attached and I would like to make this as painless as possible. I would also like to make it removable so I can change lights. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your LEDs emit UV? Many don't.

Comment: It seems like they are. They're lighting a closet and there are some serious fade marks on some of the clothing. I suppose it could also potentially just be heat, but I think putting up a barrier should help either way.

Comment: Gorilla glue or super glue might work.

Comment: Just remember Gorilla glue expands like crazy. (I've forgotten this on several projects of my own.)

Comment: Sorry y'all, cheated and ended up doing what I said everyone couldn't and drilled another angle in there to let the plexi slide in and out. Much thanks for the answers though.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest good old [J-B Weld](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001OBU3RO) for joining plexiglass and metal, and [thistothat](http://www.thistothat.com/cgi-bin/glue.cgi?lang=en&this=Plastic&that=Metal) agrees.

Rough up the mating surfaces with 120 grit sandpaper and be sure to clamp where you can. If you don't want the J-B Weld to show, you'll have to put the plexiglass angle above the aluminum channel. However, it will definitely be harder to get a good bond, you'll have trouble clamping it from what I can see of your design. If you don't care because it's in a closet, you could cut some scrap wood to length and place it underneath as a brace while the J-B Weld cures.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the adhesives already mentioned, as you're looking for something that could be removed if necessary, I'd suggest 3M VHB.  It's similar to what's in the 3M command hooks (although stronger ... it'll take the paint off walls), but it's not as strong in shear, so it's possible to remove things by twisting when you have to.

It's sold in rolls ... you cut a piece to length, leaving the waxed paper on once side, place it on one piece, and rub the waxed paper to work out any bubbles and affix it well.  Then you peel off the paper, put the two pieces together, and press to bond.

Depending on how heavy the filter is, and how long it is, you might be able to get away with just an inch of the VHB every foot or so, which will make it much easier to remove later.

Comment: Some of the foam-backed tapes might work okay, too, but you'll likely need more of it.

Answer (score 1):

Velcro will work if the light doesn't get hot enough to melt the adhesive. That will be removable. The trade off is that it's flexible, so you'll need to make sure the pieces don't need the velcro to hold them in a precise position.